# windows 10 hard drive permission errors

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

I'm having trouble with my newly installed hard drive, when ever I format it I can use it as normal and change permissions and ownership but after restarting my pc I get permission errors and cant install or move files to the drive and have to re format to use it again this is my 3rd hard drive and this problem also happened with my first 2 hard drives but I cant remember how I fixed them. would anyone be able to help fix this problem. ownership of the drive defaults to system upon reformatting ive tried changing it to my user but still does not work also default permissions work until i restart the pc i think its something to do with inheritance but cant find anything wrong on that front ive also tried using the cmd to takeown and icacls commands but get access denied after restarting

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should [edit] your question and use the Image button to upload your pictures so everyone can see them.

Comment: done. thanks Ramhound

Comment: Your first screenshot shows the permissions of Authenticated User which isn't helpful, what are the permissions of Users and Administrators.  Is the owner of the folder, a user that actually exists on the system?

Comment: users and administrators have full control before and after restarting and yea the owner is my account and im an administrator

Comment: We need screenshots....I assume the user you are attempting to access the drive with is a member of the `Desktop-9lhpdig\Users` group?  Try changing the the owner to something other than a specific owner.  The default permissions of an external drive should allow any user (from any machine) access to the drive.  Are you changing the permissions?  I won't consider any information in a comment once I start writing my answer.  Be sure you are editing your question instead of submitting commentary

Comment: Yea it is and even if i reformat and make a new principal and give this user full control it still doesn't work after restarting my pc

Comment: You really should [edit] your question instead of replying with commentary.

Comment: working on it sorry, im abit new to this

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's a data disk and not a system disk (one where you install programs on, like C:), you can try running this command in an elevated command prompt (meaning you open command prompt with administrator privileges):

```
icacls "D:\*" /q /c /t /reset
```

This should reset permission for all files and folders under D:.

As @Ramhound noted, you would need default permissions on D:\ first, meaning you would probably have to re-format your drive before running the command.

You can find Microsoft documentation on icalcs utility [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls).

Comment: Would that not require the user to have permissions, based on the screenshots, after a reboot the user doesn’t have any permissions except maybe read (but unclear since the screenshots are showing the wrong user)

Comment: You are right, the user would probably have to have to re-format his drive to get default permissions for D: before running this command. I will include it in my answer. Not sure if it will work in this case, but it's worth trying. It solved weird permission issues for me some time ago.

Comment: Tried this fix but still having same problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Should I delete my answer now we know that it did not help?

Comment: That’s entirely up to you.